# Predict with only one observation with randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

I am studying loan default prediction. I am currently using R's "randomForest" package. My first model had a accuracy of 98% with sensitivity of 0.98 and specificity of 0.97 on the test data with the "predict" command.
The training and testing data had an "n" of 2865 and 319 observations, respectively.

**In a real situation, where I would like to predict the probability of loan default for just one company, ie only 1 observation in the test data, would I have a problem?**

**The dataset I used contains only 8 predictor variables and 1 predicted variable. According to the literature, there are many more variables to be considered. Why did I get good results with just a small dataset I used? Seems "weird" to me.**

Comment: Did you use cross-validation to tune any hyper-parameters? Are your classes sized equally? You might be overfitting, but we cannot guess that from your post. Why would you expect a model to have lower accuracy?

Comment: I didn't use cross-validation to adjust the hyper-parameters. I didn't use any balancing method because as I'm starting now and the response variable didn't seem so unbalanced, I didn't use it. How do I know if there is overfitting? Some articles I've read use more and more variables and also use cross-validation and resampling of data. I have few variables and a small n, so I found it strange.

Comment: Random Forest is internally cross validated provided you don't have replicate datapoints in the training set (e.g. stats on the same company from two years). I don't know why `predict` wouldn't work with only 1 observation, but I think you could also just add it to the training corpus and see how the model classifies it.